# how to bold day and time with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to post hours on my website and I want the day and time to bold automatically based on javascript. Is it possible to setup some javascript so that on Monday  would be bold and then on tuesday  would be bold and so on?

Here is the code:

```
<div id="monday">Monday: 12:00-2:00</div>
<div id="tuesday">Tuesday: 11:00-3:00</div>
```

and so on for each day. When a user accesses the site on a Monday, I want the monday div to bold everything that is in there. When a user accesses the site on a tuesday, I want the entire tuesday div to bold.

Thanks

Comment: Care to include some more detail? what page? post your code for the page

Comment: You're going to have to give a lot more detail. You want the words "Monday", "Tuesday", etc., to be bold, in a string of text?

Comment: sorry, ive added more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/c5bHx/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>title</title></head>
    <body>

        <!-- your content -->

             <!-- place this just inside your closing </body> tag -->
        <script type="text/javascript>
            var days = 'sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday'.split(',');
            document.getElementById( days[(new Date()).getDay()] ).className = 'bold';
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*css*

```
.bold {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here's a breakdown of what is happening. I'm going to make it much more verbose, expanding the code into different variables so it is easier to see.

```
   // This simply creates a string of days in the week
var days = 'sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday';

   // This splits the string on the commas, turning it into an Array of weekdays
days = days.split(',');

   // Create a new Date object, representing today's date and time
var date = new Date();

   // Get the number of the day of the week. 0 if sunday, 1 if monday, etc...
var dayNumber = date.getDay();

   // Using the "dayNumber", get the day string by its index from the "days" array
var dayString = days[ dayNumber ];

   // Select the element on the page that has the ID that matches the "dayString"
var dayElement = document.getElementById( dayString );

   // Set the "class" property of the "dayElement" to the "bold" class.
dayElement.className = "bold";
```

Note that the conversion of a String of days into an Array isn't necessary. Just a little shorter and quicker to type.

You could do:

```
var days = ['sunday','monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday'];
```

This creates an Array, so you wouldn't need to do the `.split()`.

Comment: if you dont mind me asking, why does it only work when the code is placed near the closing </body> tag? when i tried it in the head or at the beginning of the body, it didnt work.
also, would you mind explaining what all this means:                        ( days[(new Date()).getDay()] ).className . Thanks

Comment: @golf_nut: The reason I have it at the bottom is that `getElementById()` is selecting the element. The element must exist before it can be selected, so if the code is placed *before* the weekday elements, there'll be nothing to find. There are other ways to accomplish this as well, but placement at the bottom is a very good way to do it. I'll add to my answer with further explanation of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the day and time to be bold just squirt of the relevant  or  **tag around the day/time (or even the entire datetime) in javascript with document.write, or manipulate javascript elements with jQuery, eg. **day**time**?

Answer (score 0):

If you can put any tag around your time text there is no reason to have JS involved for formating - with same efford you can formating from your script like putting tags, however if can not do it only solution (with this amount of details) is scaning whole page or elected elements, look for datatime pattern, reformat it and return to page (regular expression will be helpful)

Ok we got some details....

```
var x = document.getElementByID('monday').innerHTML;
document.getElementByID('monday').innerHTML = '<B>' + x + '</B>';
```